# Correct syntax for shell script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sh

Am trying to create one and add the same to the cron.
This is the commands I am trying to run through the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -mmin -60 -name "*.jpg" $(printf "! -name %s " $(cat processed.txt) ! -name cache) -exec convert -resize 1000x800 -quality 85% {} {};
find  -mmin -60 -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec basename {} \; &> processed.txt
```

f I am running these commands directly on shell, I don't get any error.
but if say I have stored this in a file called compress and run the script as ./compress
I get the error -

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

what mistake I am making and how I can fix that.

Comment: You have two `find` commands, both having the `-exec` option. Which of them fail?

Comment: cannot say - on the console only it prints the error I have written. as I have tried taking out each statement one by one and there is no error. when both lines are present then only it is throwing the error.

Comment: Could it have something to do with one `find` missing a path to search in? Perhaps it's the missing backslash before the semicolon to terminate the `-exec` in the first `find` command?

Comment: Hmm. I added the backslash as you suggested and run the commnd agin, but still the same error.

Comment: Also, how about the order of the commands? The *second* command creates the file `processes.txt` which the *first* command uses...

Comment: yes that is correct. but on the first run that file will be empty. so be it.

Comment: Put an `echo whatever` between both commands, so that you know which one if failing.

Comment: I did that and the result is like this:`find: missing argument to `-exec'`
success
`./compress: line 3: $'\r': command not found. I am trying these commands in widnows bash shell.
so it looks like it is failing on the first line. as echo success is after the error. I had added `echo "success" ` after 1st line

Comment: Even when I removed the second command and leave the echo line I am getting that error, but if remove the echo line as well then there is no error.

Comment: @Pawan You need to use files with Unix newlines (LF only), not Windows (CR/LF pairs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an array of arguments for the first `find` command instead of relying on the command substitution.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  processed+=(! -name "$line")
done < processed.txt
```

Your immediate problem, though, is that you forgot to escape the semicolon so that it would be treated as an argument to `find`, rather than a command terminator.

```
find . -mmin -60 -name "*.jpg" "${processed[@]}"  \
  ! -name cache  -exec convert -resize 1000x800 -quality 85% {} {} \;
#                                                                  ^^
find  -mmin -60 -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec basename {} \; &> processed.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Chepner. This works perfect. where I can have reference for building this shell script?